# unbind all in event string using jQuery one()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking for any interaction using JQuery's `.one()` function.

```
    var myEvents = 'mousedown mousemove mouseup touchstart touchmove touchend mouseout';

    jQuery(document).one(myEvents, function(){
        //do something only once.
});
```

But I would like all these to be ubinded once any of these events has fired. I know I can unbind again with `jQuery(document).unbind(myEvents)`, but was wondering if there was a clean inbuilt way of simply unbinding after one event.

EDIT: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HkQy/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend jQuery with a function which serves exactly that purpose.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    oneForAll: function(events, handler) {
        var that = this,
            oneForAll = function() {
                that.unbind(events, oneForAll);
                handler.apply(this, arguments);
            };

        that.on(events, oneForAll); 
    }
});
```

You would use it exactly the way you used `one` it would just be `oneForAll`.

JSFiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4X5J/)

Comment: I am marking this as correct as it offers the best way of keeping everything clean without a native jQuery solution. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
jQuery(document).one('mousedown mousemove mouseup touchstart touchmove touchend mouseout', function (event) {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.type);
    jQuery('p').append(event.originalEvent.type);
    //remove all handlers
    jQuery(document).off('mousedown mousemove mouseup touchstart touchmove touchend mouseout');
});
```

But i would recommend using a namespaced handlers so that you won't remove any other event handlers by mistake.

```
jQuery(document).one('mousedown.myonce mousemove.myonce mouseup.myonce touchstart.myonce touchmove.myonce touchend.myonce mouseout.myonce', function (event) {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.type);
    jQuery('p').append(event.originalEvent.type);
    //remove all handlers
    jQuery(document).off('.myonce');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9kCcQ/)

Comment: event namespacing might be better.

Comment: If there are no other events bound to document, can't you just do .off()?

Comment: Also `jQuery(document).off('.myonce')` can it not be just `$(this).off(...` although there might not be any performance diference

Comment: Using .off is the same kind of solution as using .unbind() although the preferred syntax now (should have checked the docs for unbind(). I am wondering if we can remove redundancy and remove all those events automatically, similar to how just specifying one event will then automatically remove the listener.